# Overlapping Genes

Tags: java, dna-sequence

I'm trying to run my program, but I'm getting a lot of extra, unnecessary  information. If you scroll down in the output window, the second set of genes are the correct ones, where no overlapping occurs, instead of the first set. I'm also getting total 202 genes, when I should only be getting 89.

There's this other part that's really confusing me; in my code output there's a lot of CGRatio and length data; how do I organize it so that the program will only give me how many CGRatio >0.35 there are, and how many number of strings that are longer than 60 characters in length. Note: CGRatio is the number of c's and g's in a string of DNA divided by the length of the string.
I'd also like to know how many characters there are in this file.

Note: the main method has been altered to be printGenes, because the BlueJ environment can't call main. 
Note: We haven't learned how to use anything other than the basics; StorageResource class, DirectoryResource class, and FileResource class are what has been taught in this class, from the Duke library so far (ie.

```
import java.io.*;
import edu.duke.FileResource;
import edu.duke.StorageResource;
import edu.duke.DirectoryResource;
```

)
And just basic manipulating strings and for and while loops.

Here's the file used in the program: http://www.dukelearntoprogram.com/course2/data/dna.zip

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import edu.duke.FileResource;
import edu.duke.StorageResource;
import edu.duke.DirectoryResource;

public class FindMultiGenes5 {
    public int findStopIndex(String dna, int index) {
        int stop1 = dna.indexOf("TGA", index);
        if (stop1 == -1 || (stop1 - index) % 3 != 0) {
            stop1 = dna.length();
        }
        int stop2 = dna.indexOf("TAA", index);
        if (stop2 == -1 || (stop2 - index) % 3 != 0) {
            stop2 = dna.length();
        }
        int stop3 = dna.indexOf("TAG", index);
        if (stop3 == -1 || (stop3 - index) % 3 != 0) {
            stop3 = dna.length();
        }
        return Math.min(stop1, Math.min(stop2, stop3));
    }

    public StorageResource storeAll(String dna) {

        String sequence = dna.toUpperCase();
        StorageResource store = new StorageResource();
        int index = 0;


        while (true) {
            index = sequence.indexOf("ATG", index);
            if (index == -1)
                break;

            int stop = findStopIndex(sequence, index + 3);

            if (stop != sequence.length()) {
                String gene = dna.substring(index, stop + 3);
                store.add(gene);

                System.out.println("From: " + index + " to " + stop + " Gene: " + gene );//index = sequence.substring(index, stop + 3).length();
            index = stop + 3; // start at the end of the stop codon
          }else{  index = index + 3;
        }

    }
    return store;//System.out.println(sequence);
    }
   public void testStorageFinder() {
      DirectoryResource dr = new DirectoryResource();
      StorageResource dnaStore = new StorageResource(); 
    for (File f : dr.selectedFiles()) {
        FileResource fr = new FileResource(f);
        String s = fr.asString();
        dnaStore = storeAll(s);
        printGenes(dnaStore);
    }


        System.out.println("size = " + dnaStore.size());

    }  
  public String readStrFromFile(){

        FileResource readFile = new FileResource();

        String DNA = readFile.asString();

        //System.out.println("DNA: " + DNA);

        return DNA;

    }//end readStrFromFile() method;
  public float calCGRatio(String gene){

        gene = gene.toUpperCase();  
        int len = gene.length();
        int CGCount = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<len; i++){

            if(gene.charAt(i) == 'C' || gene.charAt(i) == 'G')
                CGCount++;

        }//end for loop

        System.out.println("CGCount " + CGCount + " Length: " + len + " Ratio: " + (float)CGCount/len);
        return (float)CGCount/len;
    }//end of calCGRatio() method;
    public void printGenes(StorageResource sr){
   for(String gene: sr.data()){
     if (gene.length() > 60) {
       System.out.println(gene.length()+"\t"+gene);
     }
     if(calCGRatio(gene)> 0.35) {
       System.out.println(gene.length()+"\t"+gene);
      }
  }

        //create a FindMultiGenesFile object FMG
        FindMultiGenes5 FMG = new FindMultiGenes5();

        //read a DNA sequence from file
        String dna = FMG.readStrFromFile();



        FMG.storeAll(dna);

        //store all genes into a document
        StorageResource dnaStore = new StorageResource();



        int longerthan60 = 0;
        int CGGreaterthan35 = 0;





        System.out.println("\n There are " + dnaStore.size() + " genes. ");
        System.out.println("There are " + longerthan60 + " genes longer than 60.");
        System.out.println("There are " + CGGreaterthan35 + " genes with CG ratio greater than 0.35.");
    }//end main();
}
```

Comment: If this is homework then please tell us what you are allowed / not allowed to use. Otherwise you might get unusable answers.

Comment: I've added info on how much we've gone over in class. Hope it helps. If not tell me here and I'll give more detailed explanation.